# How to fix printing errors in the code

Tags: python

There are a few problems with my code that I don't know how to fix.

1. When I am printing out the message of what game and the level they chose,  at the end, it isn't printing out the level (beginner, intermediate or advanced). It only prints out the game. I have put 'num' to print it but i have also tried 'Level' and 'number' in place. The code is

   print ("Play",gamelist[gametype], "at" ,num)
2. When asking the user what game they would like to play, if they input a number out of the range of 0-3 or a letter it breaks further down in the code when printing the message at the end. This is only when asking what game, not the level they want the game at.

Anything to help would be appreciated.

```
#Ask user what game they would like to play
def game () :
    global gametype,gamelist
    gamelist = ["Mario Cart","Minecraft","Angry Birds","Grabd Theft Auto"]
    gamecount = 0
    print ("Hello",name,"the four games avaliable are:")
    while gamecount < 4:
        print (gamecount," ",gamelist[gamecount])
        gamecount = gamecount + 1
    gametype = int(input("What number game do you want? (Please choose between 0 and 3) "))
    print ( "You have chosen",gamelist[gametype],)
    print ("")

#Ask game level
def number():
    while True:
        try:
            Level = int(input("What is the level you would like to play at? "))

            if Level <= 25:
                print ("Begginer ")
                break

            elif Level >=26 and Level <=75:
                print ("Intermediate")
                break

            elif Level >=76 and Level <=100:
                print ("Advanced")
                break
            else:
                print("Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number:")

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")

#Create a subroutine to print out the action message
def printmessage ():

    print ("")
    print ("#                                                      #")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#################### ACTION MESSAGE ####################")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#                                                      #")
    print ("Play",gamelist[gametype], "at" ,num)
    print ("#                                                      #")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#################### ACTION MESSAGE ####################")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#                                                      #")

#This is to let the program work
name = input("What is your name? ")
print ("")

game ()
num = number()
printmessage()
```

Comment: see your code,  gamecount = 0 then print (gamecount," ",gamelist[gamecount]) you can't concatenate a string with an integer so you need convert everything to string like print (str(gamecount)+" "+gamelist[gamecount])

Comment: it still isn't working when i do that

Comment: can you give me the error please? in any case u have more errors: print ("Hello",name,"the four games avaliable are:") what is name? you can't concatenate  string with ",", you need "+" update your code, your question and introduce the error message please, otherwise it will be impossible to help u

Comment: in any case: print ("Play",gamelist[gametype], "at" ,num) should be print ("Play"+str(gamelist[gametype])+ "at" +str(num))

Comment: if i do that, instead of printing 'play minecraft at advanced' it says 'play minecraft at none'

Comment: in def printmessage (): you are not passing anything so for them num doesn't exist, or you set-up num as global variable or you have to pass the value to printmessage function. If I have some time I'll fix it for u

Comment: Please see my answer, if you need some help to understand better just let me know, I didn't improve your code, I left the same structure I just make it working ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put comment with the changes:

```
#Ask user what game they would like to play
def game (name) :
    global gametype,gamelist
    gamelist = ["Mario Cart","Minecraft","Angry Birds","Grabd Theft Auto"]
    gamecount = 0
    print ("Hello "+name+" the four games avaliable are:")
    while gamecount < 4:
        print (gamecount," ",gamelist[gamecount])
        gamecount = gamecount + 1
    gametype = int(input("What number game do you want? (Please choose between 0 and 3) "))
    print ( "You have chosen "+gamelist[gametype])
    print ("")

#Ask game level
def number():
    while True:
        try:
            Level = int(input("What is the level you would like to play at? "))

            if Level <= 25:
                print ("Begginer ")
                return("Begginer ")#changed break with return so it will break and return the selected value

            elif Level >=26 and Level <=75:
                print ("Intermediate")
                return("Intermediate ")#changed break with return so it will break and return the selected value

            elif Level >=76 and Level <=100:
                print ("Advanced")
                return("Advanced ")#changed break with return so it will break and return the selected value
            else:
                print("Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number:")

        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")

#Create a subroutine to print out the action message
def printmessage (num):

    print ("")
    print ("#                                                      #")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#################### ACTION MESSAGE ####################")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#                                                      #")
    print ("Play "+gamelist[gametype]+" at "+num)
    print ("#                                                      #")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#################### ACTION MESSAGE ####################")
    print ("########################################################")
    print ("#                                                      #")

#This is to let the program work
name = raw_input("What is your name? ") # I changed input with raw_input because you are sending a string not integer
print ("")

game (name)
num = number()
printmessage(num)
```

This is the Output:

```
What is your name? Test

Hello Test the four games avaliable are:
(0, ' ', 'Mario Cart')
(1, ' ', 'Minecraft')
(2, ' ', 'Angry Birds')
(3, ' ', 'Grabd Theft Auto')
What number game do you want? (Please choose between 0 and 3) 0
You have chosen Mario Cart

What is the level you would like to play at? 1000
Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number:
What is the level you would like to play at? 1
Begginer 

#                                                      #
########################################################
#################### ACTION MESSAGE ####################
########################################################
#                                                      #
Play Mario Cart at Begginer 
#                                                      #
########################################################
#################### ACTION MESSAGE ####################
########################################################
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code at the end of function def number:

```
return Level
```

Comment: what does that do? because i'm not sure

Comment: It returns the resulted level at the end of function "number()" so you can store the return results when num = number(). If you don't return the value you just store a dump value in num. That is why it does not print the num properly.

Comment: it still says 'play game at none' rather than 'play game at a level'

Comment: level being beginner etc and game being angry birds etc

Comment: def number():
  while True:
     try:
        Level = int(input("What is the level you would like to play at? "))
            if Level <= 25:
              print ("Begginer ")
                break
          elif Level >=26 and Level <=75:
              print ("Intermediate")
                break
         elif Level >=76 and Level <=100:
               print ("Advanced")
                break
           else:
               print("Out Of range(1-100): Please enter a valid number:")
       except ValueError:
          print("Please enter a valid number")
return level

Comment: Python is CaSe SeNsItIvE. return Level not level. I ran your code on my machine and it prints the level if you return Level